# Encryption algorithm preferably having an implementation in java

Tags: java, encryption, key, encryption-symmetric, base32

I am looking for a symmetric key encryption scheme which would encrypt my 12 byte data. As you can see it does not conform to 64 bit or 128 bit boundaries for me to use block ciphering algorithms and I do not want to pad the data as I have restriction on the length of encrypted data. The restriction is because I would be transforming using base 32 it to a printable key which cannot exceed 20 chars. The plain text has very predictable data pattern, so the encryption scheme should be able to hide that. From what I understand, the pseudo random key generation is the only soultion fo this problem, but the solution that encrypts the data and solution that decrypts it, do not talk to each other.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use RC4?  The cipher text is the exact same size as the clear text - in your case 12 bytes.  It comes with Java (5 or greater).  Here is an example:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class MyArcFour
{
   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
   {
      byte [] key = "MYVERYINSECUREKEY".getBytes("ASCII");

      String clearText = "123456789012";

      Cipher rc4 = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
      SecretKeySpec rc4Key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "RC4");
      rc4.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);

      byte [] cipherText = rc4.update(clearText.getBytes("ASCII"));

      System.out.println("clear (ascii)        " + clearText);
      System.out.println("clear (hex)          " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(clearText.getBytes("ASCII")));
      System.out.println("cipher (hex) is      " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipherText));

      Cipher rc4Decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
      rc4Decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, rc4Key);
      byte [] clearText2 = rc4Decrypt.update(cipherText);

      System.out.println("decrypted (clear) is " + new String(clearText2, "ASCII"));
   }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
clear (ascii)        123456789012
clear (hex)          313233343536373839303132
cipher (hex) is      CBFB9A712E55EBD985C8F2DF
decrypted (clear) is 123456789012
```

Of course you would want to use a better (longer, more random) key than in the example.

Comment: Thank you user1657364! But as I said as long as the key remains same, the cipher text is coming out to be predictable. I tried encrypting "1234DifferentText" and I got CBFB9A715F0ABA87D98AA68380298E4F46. The first part of the cipher text remained the same which indicates the data pattern.

Comment: I don't now much about RC4 in specific, but being it a stream cipher, then the same byte, in the same position, with the same history (i.e., the bytes before), ciphered with the same key, should obviously always produce the same ciphered byte.

Comment: I get an error when I try this code... java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stream cypher like RC4, but as you have found, you **cannot** reuse the key.  For a stream cypher use a key/nonce (nonce = Number used ONCE) combination.  The nonce can be as simple as 1, 2, 3, 4, ... or a date/time and will need to be stored alongside the cyphertext.  Change the key before the nonce recycles round to zero and starts to repeat.  If you use a date/time then ensure that the clock ticks fast enough never to repeat a value.

You have a long term key and a nonce.  Each time you want to encrypt something, hash them to get a session key:

```
sessionKey <- SHA256(longTermKey + nonce)
```

Use this session key once only, then throw it away.  Store the nonce for use in decrypting.  Increment a numerical nonce ready for the next use.  For date/time nonces insert a short delay to ensure the clock has changed.  The nonce **must** be different the next time it is used.

When you change the long term key, you will need to decrypt and re-encrypt all your data.  Alternatively pick a large bit-size for your nonce and keep your long term key *very* secure.

Answer (score 0):

You want/need a stream cipher: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher